# find the value of variable given in a string

Tags: java

Given a equation :

```
433+4H8= 871
```

`H` can be anyside of equation. Find the value of H and replace it in given equation.

The output should be :

```
433+438=871
```

I have tried the following code but conversion of string to int does not work...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.io.*;

class hole

{

    public static void main(String[] args) 

    {

        Scanner reader= new Scanner(System.in);

        int[] nums= new int[3];

        String str= reader.nextLine();

        String str_1= str.replaceAll("=","+");

        String[] split= str_1.split("[+]");

        for (int k=0; k<split.length; k++)
        {

            String ex= split[k];
            nums[k]= Integer.parseInt(ex);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Do you get any exception? Maybe it has meaningful message for you...

Comment: parseInt can not parse an expression

Comment: at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)

Comment: Please add the full exception stacktrace to your question.

Comment: then how to solve it....

Answer (score 0):

Why would you not just subtract the final answer minus the first number and build the third number. Splitting the string is redundant as you can just use simple math to solve for x.

```
871-433 = 438
h=3



public static void main(String[] args) 

{
    int a = 433;
    int b = 871;
    int c = b - a;
    String s = "4H8";
    char x;
    int location = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
      char d = s.charAt(i);
      if(d.isDigit()){

          }
      else{
        location = i;
        x = d;

        }
     }

    String solve = c.toString();

  System.out.println(x + "=" + solve.charAt(location) );
  }
```

Comment: I did this in the dark off the top of my head, let me know if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

`4H8` isn't an integer, so `parseInt` won't work on it.

It seems like you still have a bit of a way to go on this, so I won't spoil your fun by giving you the code, just some ideas.

Assuming the equation is always `X + Y = Z`, which X, Y and Z being some integers, one of which can contain an `H`...

You need to have a couple of cases:

- If the `H` is in `X`, you can get `X` by subtracting `Y` from `Z`.
- If the `H` is in `Y`, you can get `Y` by subtracting `X` from `Z`.
- If the `H` is in `Z`, you can get `Z` by adding `X` and `Y`.

But this still doesn't give you `H`. For this, you can simply find the position of the `H` in the string we have and extract the digit at that position in the number calculated above.

So before calling `parseInt`, you should look for the `H` and simply store the string instead if you find it.

`parseInt` also doesn't like spaces, so you should remove those in some way or another.

If equations aren't always in the form `X + Y = Z` (i.e. you can also have subtraction, multiplication, division and/or multiple terms), it gets a bit more complicated.

Comment: but how to get X,Y and Z from a string??

Comment: after getting the string dey are not converting to integerfor addition or subtraction

Comment: You're already converting them to integer with `parseInt`, you just need to check for the `H` and remove the spaces (assuming there can be spaces).

Comment: the main problem is wen i convert it using parseint it gives numberformatexception

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[] nums = new int[3];
    boolean[] isNum = new boolean[3];

    String str = reader.nextLine();

    // String str_1= str.replaceAll("=","+");

    String[] split = str.split("[+=]");
    int i = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < split.length; k++) {

        try {
            String s = split[k];
            isNum[k] = true;
            nums[i] = Integer.parseInt(s);i++;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            isNum[k] = false;
        }
    }
    int tot ;
    if(str.indexOf("H")>str.indexOf("=")){
        tot = nums[1] + nums[0];

    }else{
        tot = nums[1] - nums[0];
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < split.length; k++) {
        if(!isNum[k]){
            int indx = split[k].indexOf("H");
            String h = Integer.toString(tot).charAt(indx)+"";
            h = str.replace("H",h);
            System.out.println("New expression :"+h);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below program , This works only for input a+b=c format
Below program is giving correct output

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hole {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int hLocation = 0;
        int result;
        char hValue;
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        String str=in.nextLine().replaceAll(" ", "");
        String[] split= str.split("[+=]");

        for(int i=0;i<split.length;i++){
            if(split[i].contains("H")){
                hLocation=i;
                }
        }
        if(hLocation==0){
            result=Integer.parseInt(split[2])-Integer.parseInt(split[1]);
        }else if(hLocation==1){
            result=Integer.parseInt(split[2])-Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
        }
        else{
            result=Integer.parseInt(split[0])+Integer.parseInt(split[1]);
         }

        hValue= String.valueOf(result).charAt(1);
        str=str.replace('H', hValue);
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated - decreased no of lines

Answer (score 0):

Try this (comments are self explanatory):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] nums = new int[3];
    int varIndex = 0;
    int result = 0;

    String str = reader.nextLine();

    //remove spaces and split into 3 parts based on symbols
    String[] components = str.replaceAll(" ", "").split("\\+|=");
    for (int i = 0; i < components.length; i++) {
        try {
            nums[i] = Integer.parseInt(components[i]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            varIndex = i; //this component contains "H"
        }
    }

    //Calculate the value of the number which has "H"
    switch (varIndex) {
    case 0:
        result = nums[2] - nums[1]; break;
    case 1:
        result = nums[2] - nums[0]; break;
    case 2:
        result = nums[0] + nums[1]; break;
    }
    nums[varIndex] = result;

    //Print the output
    System.out.println(nums[0] + " + " + nums[1] + " = " + nums[2]);
    System.out.println("H = " + (String.valueOf(result)).charAt(components[varIndex].indexOf('H')));
}
```